# Unable to delete material object in change record- CC02

Tags: sap-erp

We have a scenario, our user usually makes a revision in material management and assign in to a change number, sometimes the user wants to delete the revision as he has made a mistake, so he got to Transaction code (tcode) `CC12` to remove the revision and he goes to Tcode CC02 to delete the Material object assigned to the change number .

But for a particular material he is getting an error message:

> Not all objects were deleted 
> Message no. CC008 
> Diagnosis 
> You have selected one or more management records in the object overview and chosen function Delete object. 
> Objects have already been changed with one or more management records. For this reason, they cannot be deleted.

We are unable to find the exact cause of this error, as we are getting this error even after removing the revision level in Tcode: CC12.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this document already has a revision level assigned, that's why SAP doesn't allow to delete it. Another possible reason is that other BOMs in that BOM group have already been changed.

Full list of possible reasons for delete prohibition can be found [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/e2/24bd534f22b44ce10000000a174cb4/content.htm?frameset=/en/24/15b8535c39b44ce10000000a174cb4/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/d8/25bd534f22b44ce10000000a174cb4/plain.htm&node_id=68)